# Un-editing / removing focus from a Vaadin TextField

Tags: java, web-applications, vaadin

Does anyone know how to cancel the editing state of a Vaadin TextField that's inside a Table? My concrete use case is that I have a table with multiple TextFields in it, that show different values when they are edited as opposed to viewed. The user clicks on a TextField, this makes the field display its editable content. If the user changes his mind and wants to stop editing the field (by pressing ESC) the field should cancel any changes the user might have made to its content and revert to displaying its view value.

So far I've been able to move the focus to another TextField but this is not what I ultimately want to achieve. Moving the focus to the parent Table would be acceptable, but doing so programmatically by calling `table.focus()` does not produce any visible results.

Thanks for your help,

Radu

Answer (score 0):

To revert the value of any field - including TextField - before it gets committed, [AbstractField#discard()](https://vaadin.com/api/7.0.5/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html#discard%28%29)

Comment: Thanks Charles, that does not completely solve my problem but is still

Comment: I have the same problem, but I have my TextFields generated in a TableFieldFactory. I don't know how to cancel what a user has typed in a TextField, because I don't have access to the TextField objects as the TableFieldFactory createField() just returns the fields. Any clues?

Comment: @Roger Simply cast to AbstractField (i.e. `((AbstractField) field).discard()`. You can surround by instanceof for safety - but, essentially, all implementations of Field in the core Vaadin library extend AbstractField

Comment: Yes, I guess you can also just use `field.discard()`, but the problem is that I cannot reach the fields, as they are created in the createField() method of the TableFieldFactory and when they have been created the are immediately returned from that method. When I click the "Cancel" button I have nothing to do discard on. I have also tried doing discard on the Table without success.

Comment: What cancel button? Essentially, need much more information to help (code - at least an outline), what and where you want to discard what etc; sounds more like a job for the Vaadin Forum https://vaadin.com/forum)

Comment: Yes, my follow up question might have been a little bit out of context there. If you have a minute, you could go check it out at https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/4043140. Thanks!